# Spring Batch disable set of jobs

Tags: java, cron, spring-batch

I need to be able to enable/disable a set of jobs just changing a configuration value.

What I have done so far looks like this.

```
<property name="cronExpression" value="#{${child.system.batch.jobs.enabled}==true?'${batch.poll.queue.cron.expression}':'0 0 0 1 1 ? 2099'}" />
```

That pretty much what it does is check **child.system.batch.jobs.enabled** if that's enabled, just use the configured cron expression, but if it's disabled, just put a cron in the future.

That seemed clean to me. BUT, I think there is the chance that we want to run all the batch jobs at startup at some point, configuring like this:

```
spring.batch.job.enabled=true
```

But if we do this, the solution I have implemented is not going to work because the job is going to be executed at startup time regardless the cron expression in the future.

So what I need is something like

```
<job id="myJob" enabled="${child.system.batch.jobs.enabled}" >
```

But I don't know if it's feasible. For sure I don't want to add a property to each job and programmatically check inside the java code if the flag is enabled or disabled.

Thanks!